# Split routes.py by apps in aiohttp

Tags: python, aiohttp

I have project structure like:

```
apps
    app1
        __init__.py
        views.py
    app2
        __init__.py
        views.py
    __init__.py
    main.py
    routes.py
```

How to split routes by apps, put them into their own app and include them in "global" router like django's include do?

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

**In apps\app1\views.py**

```
from aiohttp import web

async def route_path_def(request):
    return web.Response(body=b'Some response')

routes = (
    {'GET', '/route_path', route_path_def, 'route_path_name'}
)
```

**In apps\app2\views.py**

```
from aiohttp import web

async def another_route_path_def(request):
    return web.Response(body=b'Some response')

routes = (
    {'GET', '/another_route_path', another_route_path_def, 'another_route_path_name'}
)
```

**In routes.py**

from app1.views import routes as app1_routes
    from app2.views import routes as app2_routes

```
routes = list()
routes.append(app1_routes)
routes.extend(app2_routes)
```

**In main.py**

```
from .routes import routes
from aiohttp import web

app = web.Application()

for method, path, func_name, page_name in routes:
    app.router.add_route(method, path, func_name, name=page_name)
web.run_app(app, port=5000)
```

Worked for me just fine :)